# Issues using Keras np_utils.to_categorical

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to make an array of one-hot vector of integers into an array of one-hot vector that keras will be able to use to fit my model. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
Y_train = np.hstack(np.asarray(dataframe.output_vector)).reshape(len(dataframe),len(output_cols))
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train)
```

Below is an image showing what `Y_train` and `dummy_y` actually are.

[image]

I couldn't find any documentation for `to_categorical` that could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Y_train is already a one-hot vector, you can use that directly and there is no need to use to_categorical, what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 34):

`np_utils.to_categorical` is used to convert array of labeled data(from `0` to `nb_classes - 1`) to one-hot vector.

The official doc with an example.

```
In [1]: from keras.utils import np_utils # from keras import utils as np_utils
Using Theano backend.

In [2]: np_utils.to_categorical?
Signature: np_utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=None)
Docstring:
Convert class vector (integers from 0 to nb_classes) to binary class matrix, for use with categorical_crossentropy.

# Arguments
    y: class vector to be converted into a matrix
    nb_classes: total number of classes

# Returns
    A binary matrix representation of the input.
File:      /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/utils/np_utils.py
Type:      function

In [3]: y_train = [1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2, 1]

In [4]: """ Assuming the labeled dataset has total six classes (0 to 5), y_train is the true label array """

In [5]: np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=6)
Out[5]:
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: `nb_classes` should be `num_classes` according to documentation here: https://keras.io/utils/

Comment: In the public API, you cannot access np_util (it's internal). You are supposed to access utilities via the utils module, e.g.

from keras import utils

utils.to_categorical(...)    See this issue: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8838

Comment: @ArayanSingh Thanks for pointing, I added the import in comment.

Answer (score 10):

```
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
```

UPDATED --- `keras.utils.np_utils` doesn't work in newer versions; if so use:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
```

**In both cases**

```
to_categorical(0, max_value_of_array)
```

**It assumes the class values were in string and you will be label encoding them, hence starting everytime from 0 to n-classes.**

```
for the same example:- consider an array of {1,2,3,4,2}

The output will be [zero value, one value, two value, three value, four value]

array([[ 0.,  1.,  0., 0., 0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1., 0., 0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., 1., 0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., 0., 1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1., 0., 0.]],
```

**Let's look at another example:-**

```
Again, for an array having 3 classes, Y = {4, 8, 9, 4, 9}

to_categorical(Y) will output

array([[0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0. ],
       [0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0. ],
       [0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1. ],
       [0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0. ],
       [0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1. ]]
```