# Present ndarray of interger elements as ndarray of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having problems with vectorized function application to ndarrays.
What is a good and working way to do this?

Input:

```
y_train

array([0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2,
       1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0,
       2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Desired Output:

```
array([[0,0],
       [0,0],
       [0,1],
       [1,0],
        ...
         ..])
```

---

```
I have:

    def func(x):
        return np.array([int(x) for x in list(np.binary_repr(x,width=2,))])

   func(y_train)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-178-ca45ba935147> in <module>


TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: you want to convert it to a 2 column array?

Comment: Yes, in the end yes;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the additional chat conversation, it looks like you want to convert the (130,1) shaped array to a (130,2) shaped array where you want to replace 0 with [0,0], 1 with [1,0], and 2 with [0,1].

To do this, create a dictionary, then lookup the dictionary, and replace each element in y_train with the dictionary value.

The code is as follows:

```
y_train = [0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2,
       1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0,
       2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

d = {0:[0,0],1:[1,0],2:[0,1]}
arr = [d[i] for i in y_train]
print (arr)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

You can also achieve this using `list(map(d.get, y_train))` where `d` is the dictionary with the lookup values.

Looks like you want this to be a two 2 column array.

```
import numpy as np
y_train = [0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2,
       1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0,
       2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

ln = len(y_train) #find the length of the list
arr = np.array(y_train) #convert y_train to numpy array
arr1 = arr.reshape(ln//2,2) #convert it to length/2 for rows, 2 for columns
print (arr1)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[[0 0]
 [2 1]
 [2 0]
 [2 1]
 [0 0]
 [1 2]
 ......
[2 0]
 [0 0]
 [1 1]
 [1 1]
 [0 1]
 [1 0]
 [0 0]]
```

Comment: Probably poorly expressed. I already have ndarray y_train (130,).
I want to do such transformations to each element to get ndarray (130,2)

Comment: what do you mean transformation to get to 130,2. Where is the second value coming from?

Comment: analogue of a ready-made solution
tf.keras.utils.to_categorical

Comment: represent each element of the original ndarray of integres 0,1,2
as [0,0], [1,0], [0,1]

Comment: since you have 0, 1, 2, would it be [0.0.0], [0,1,0],[0,0,1], to determine the position where the number is? I looked at keras.utils.to_categorical and it represents as this. Example is ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494625/issues-using-keras-np-utils-to-categorical/43314437

Comment: If you want this to be done, i can generate a code for it

Comment: means not quite like in Keras
But the idea is the same
interger 0,1,2 can represent with two bits ( like so)
0,1,2 as [0,0], [1,0], [0,1]

Comment: Really! Great way! Thank you very much! The most important thing is the worker!